# Apache2 fails to find a newly created page

Tags: linux, ubuntu, httpd, apache2

I've just installed an apache server on Ubuntu, everything went well and I can access the starting page. However, I want to create another page which is located in /var/www/test. I want to be able to access it via address http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/test. I've created the directory, inserted the html file changed my config to this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/test>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But unfortunately, when I try to access this page I get an error:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correspondence between the URL space and files on the disk is ruled by Apache's [DocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive.
If you have in your main or `<VirtualHost>` configuration file a line like:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

(you probably have this set in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`), then whenever you ask the server for `http://example.com/path/to/file.html`, you will get the content of file `/var/www/html/path/to/file.html`.

In your case you put a file (probably) called `index.html` in `/var/www/test`, but the server is searching for `/var/www/html/test/index.html`.

The [Directory](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) section you added only specifies permissions and other options for `/var/www/test`, it does not include it in the server's search path. Besides, directory options are inherited, so the `/var/www/test` directory inherits the options from `/var/www` (no need to specify the same options again).

Comment: Thanks, I changed DocumentRoot variable to /var/www/ and it works.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have to create a new `<Directory>` block to every directory in your website. Secondly, if you're trying to access the new file without specifying its name, make sure it is an index file. For instance: You've created a `/var/www/test/index.html` file, you have a `DirectoryIndex index.html` directive (more examples and information about its use can be found in [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)) and then you try to access through your browser through `http://localhost/test` or `http://localhost/test/index.html` (I'm assuming here that you've configured the `DocumentRoot` directive pointing to the `/var/www` directory.